# d3.js multiple area charts not showing the first month

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to recreate the multiple area chart

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/

However i am not getting the first month in the draggable area.

```
<body>
    <div id="chart-container">
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 150, left: 60},
        width = 940 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        contextHeight = 50;
        contextWidth = (width * .5) + 50;
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;//declare outside the for loop

        var svg = d3.select("#chart-container").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom));

        d3.csv('data_multiplec.csv', createChart);

        function createChart(data){
            var countries = [];
            var charts = [];
            var maxDataPoint = 0;

            /* Loop through first row and get each country 
                and push it into an array to use later */
            for (var prop in data[0]) {
                if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (prop != 'Month') {
                        countries.push(prop);
                    }
                }
            };

            var countriesCount = countries.length;
            var startYear = data[0].Month;
            var endYear = data[data.length - 1].Month;
            var chartHeight = height * (1 / countriesCount);

            /* Let's make sure these are all numbers, 
                we don't want javaScript thinking it's text 

                Let's also figure out the maximum data point
                We'll use this later to set the Y-Axis scale
            */
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            for (var prop in d) {

              if (d.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
           if (prop != 'Month') {

                    d[prop] = parseFloat(d[prop]);

                if (d[prop] > maxDataPoint) {
                  maxDataPoint = d[prop];
                }
          }
              }
            }

          d.Month = (parseDate(d.Month));

          });

          for(var i = 0; i < countriesCount; i++){
            charts.push(new Chart({
                                  data: data.slice(),
                                  id: i,
                                  name: countries[i],
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height * (1 / countriesCount),
                                  maxDataPoint: maxDataPoint,
                                  svg: svg,
                                  margin: margin,
                                  showBottomAxis: (i == countries.length - 1)
                                }));

          }

          /* Let's create the context brush that will 
              let us zoom and pan the chart */
          var contextXScale = d3.time.scale()
                                .range([0, contextWidth + 240])
                                .domain(charts[0].xScale.domain()); 

          var contextAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(contextXScale)
                                  .tickSize(contextHeight)
                                  .tickPadding(-10)
                                  .orient("bottom");

          var contextArea = d3.svg.area()
                                  .interpolate("monotone")
                                  .x(function(d) { return contextXScale(d.Month); })
                                  .y0(contextHeight)
                                  .y1(0);

          var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                            .x(contextXScale)
                            .on("brush", onBrush);

          var context = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class","context")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + width * .15) + "," + (height + margin.top + chartHeight - 10) + ")");

          context.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x axis top")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                            .call(contextAxis)

          context.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x brush")
                            .call(brush)
                            .selectAll("rect")
                              .attr("y", 0)
                              .attr("height", contextHeight);

          context.append("text")
                    .attr("class","instructions")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (contextHeight + 20) + ")")
                    .text('Click and drag above to zoom / pan the data');

          function onBrush(){
            /* this will return a date range to pass into the chart object */
            var b = brush.empty() ? contextXScale.domain() : brush.extent();
            for(var i = 0; i < countriesCount; i++){
              charts[i].showOnly(b);
            }
          }
          }

          function Chart(options){
          this.chartData = options.data;
          this.width = options.width;
          this.height = options.height;
          this.maxDataPoint = options.maxDataPoint;
          this.svg = options.svg;
          this.id = options.id;
          this.name = options.name;
          this.margin = options.margin;
          this.showBottomAxis = options.showBottomAxis;

          var localName = this.name;

          /* XScale is time based */
          this.xScale = d3.time.scale()
                                .range([0, this.width])
                                .domain(d3.extent(this.chartData.map(function(d) { return d.Month; })));

          /* YScale is linear based on the maxData Point we found earlier */
          this.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .range([this.height,0])
                                .domain([0,this.maxDataPoint]);
          var xS = this.xScale;
          var yS = this.yScale;

          /* 
            This is what creates the chart.
            There are a number of interpolation options. 
            'basis' smooths it the most, however, when working with a lot of data, this will slow it down 
          */
          this.area = d3.svg.area()
                                .interpolate("basis")
                                .x(function(d) { return xS(d.Month); })
                                .y0(this.height)
                                .y1(function(d) { return yS(d[localName]); });
          /*
            This isn't required - it simply creates a mask. If this wasn't here,
            when we zoom/panned, we'd see the chart go off to the left under the y-axis 
          */
          this.svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
                                  .attr("id", "clip-" + this.id)
                                  .append("rect")
                                    .attr("width", this.width)
                                    .attr("height", this.height);
          /*
            Assign it a class so we can assign a fill color
            And position it on the page
          */
          this.chartContainer = svg.append("g")
                                    .attr('class',this.name.toLowerCase())
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + (this.margin.top + (this.height * this.id) + (10 * this.id)) + ")");

          /* We've created everything, let's actually add it to the page */
          this.chartContainer.append("path")
                              .data([this.chartData])
                              .attr("class", "chart")
                              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-" + this.id + ")")
                              .attr("d", this.area);

          this.xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale).orient("bottom");
          this.xAxisBottom = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale).orient("top");
          /* We only want a top axis if it's the first country */
          if(this.id == 0){
            this.chartContainer.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis top")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                  .call(this.xAxisTop);
          }

          /* Only want a bottom axis on the last country */
          if(this.showBottomAxis){
              this.chartContainer.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis bottom")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
                  .call(this.xAxisBottom);
            }  

          this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.yScale).orient("left").ticks(10);

          this.chartContainer.append("g")
                              .attr("class", "y axis")
                              .attr("transform", "translate(-15,0)")
                              .call(this.yAxis);

          this.chartContainer.append("text")
                              .attr("class","country-title")
                              .attr("transform", "translate(15,40)")
                              .text(this.name);

          }

          Chart.prototype.showOnly = function(b){
            this.xScale.domain(b);
            this.chartContainer.select("path").data([this.chartData]).attr("d", this.area);
            this.chartContainer.select(".x.axis.top").call(this.xAxisTop);
            this.chartContainer.select(".x.axis.bottom").call(this.xAxisBottom);
          }
          </script>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the first month i.e January is missing. I changed the contextwidth but still it is not accomodating.

The csv data is:

Japan,India,US,Russia,England,Month

1000,2000,3000,2200,1230,2013-01-12
1300,2300,2400,2288,2123,2013-01-21
300,700,600,388,500,2013-02-12
200,300,900,588,700,2013-03-12
88,300,1900,1588,1000,2013-04-12
3500,600,800,588,323,2013-04-22
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-06-12
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-07-12
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-08-12
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-09-12
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-10-12
400,1000,1800,1288,3000,2013-10-27
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-11-12
200,3000,900,588,2000,2013-12-12

Comment: Can you maybe narrow it down to the specific part that you have a problem with? It's quite a general question and a lot of code.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post a fiddle with the current version of your code.

Comment: how to post a fiddle with the current version of the code. Any help on this is highly appreciated.